# How can I create thumbnails of web pages using a layout engine in Perl?

Tags: perl, webkit, gecko

Are there bindings for layout engines like Gecko or WebKit for Perl? 
I found Gtk2-Webkit on CPAN but I would like to know if there are other options.

My idea is to use one of those engines to create thumbnails of web pages from a Perl script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but the documentation for [`WWW::Mechanize::FireFox`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize::FireFox) looks pretty impressive.

Update:

Tried it now. This rocks. You can indeed remote-control Firefox whatever way you want and create screen-shots easily.

Comment: I don't see a way to create screenshot from it's documentation.

Comment: Look at the content_as_png method.

Answer (score 3):

[XUL::Gui](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XUL::Gui) allows you to create GUI applications using Firefox. I am not sure if this corresponds to your needs, but it would be an interesting module to examine.

**Update:** `XUL::Gui` indeed is an interesting module to examine, but I did not realize how far `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` had come.

Comment: But I think that XUL::Gui supports only a subset of HTML and there is no way to have an image of the rendered content.

Comment: XUL::Gui supports all of HTML, all of XUL, and any other tag you want (created at runtime with the 'tag' and 'object' functions).  @munissor => speaking as the author, was there anything in the XUL::Gui documentation that implied a limited subset?  if so I'll be sure to fix it.

Comment: I agree with Sinan though that WWW::Mechanize::Firefox is probably a better fit for this task.

Answer (score 2):

Also [Gtk2::MozEmbed](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Gtk2-MozEmbed/)

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Wx](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Wx) and just plain [Gtk](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Gtk)